# How to add custom HTML to function link (Phoenix.HTML.link) in eex

Tags: html, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to add a custom html to link(Phoenix.HTML.link)

```
<%= link "<i class=\"fas fa-users\"></i> Login" to: "/login", class: "some class" %>

#But not working, result in this...
#HTML result:
<a class="some class" href="/login">&lt;i class="fas fa-users"&gt;&lt;/i&gt; Login</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [link](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Link.html#link/2-examples) has a `do... end` block

```
#Example of use
<%= link to: "url", class: "nav-link" do %>
    <i class="fas fa-users"></i> Login
<% end %>
```

**Here is the documentation:** 
https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Link.html

Comment: @zwippie ouch, of course, `do`-`end` block allows the HTML to get out of `<%= %>` tag, which prevents HTML escaping. Yep, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Phoenix.HTML.raw/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.html?#raw/1)

```
<%= link raw("<i class='fas fa-users'></i> Login"), ... %>
```